# Prove there are two points making two regions not conformally equivalent

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that there exist distinct points $z_0,z_1$ in the open unit disk $D$ so that $D - \{1/2, 1/3\}$ and $ D - \{z_0, z_1\}$ are not conformally equivalent.

Thoughts so far: I'm not sure where to go with this, so a hint to get me started would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $A$ and $B$ the two open sets. Assume that a biholomorphism $\phi:A\to B$ exists and call $\psi:B\to A$ its inverse.

$\phi$ and $\psi$ extend to holomorphic maps $\overline{\phi},\overline{\psi}:D\to D$ (why?) and
$\overline{\phi}\circ\overline{\psi}=\overline{\psi}\circ\overline{\phi}=id$ (why?). So $\overline{\phi}:D\to D$ is an automorphism of the disk and thus it maps $\{1/2, 1/3\}$ to $\{z_0,z_1\}$.

Now choose any $z_0\in D$ (you can choose for instance $z_0=1/2$ but it's not important). We will find a suitable $z_1$ s.t. such a $\overline{\phi}$ cannot exist. We split the problem in two cases:

If $\overline{\phi}(1/2)=z_0$: choose two automorphisms of $D$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, s.t. $\alpha(0)=1/2$ and $\beta(z_0)=0$. Now $\beta\circ\overline{\phi}\circ\alpha(0)=0$ and $\beta\circ\overline{\phi}\circ\alpha$ is an automorphism, so by Schwarz lemma $|\beta\circ\overline{\phi}(1/3)|=|\alpha^{-1}(1/3)|$ (why?), i.e. $|\beta(z_1)|=|\alpha^{-1}(1/3)|$, i.e. $z_1$ belongs to $\beta^{-1}(S_1)$, where $S_1$ is the circle centered at $0$ with radius $|\alpha^{-1}(1/3)|$.

The other case, where $\overline{\phi}(1/3)=z_0$, is completely analogous and gives $z_1\in (\beta')^{-1}(S_2)$ (now $S_2$ has radius $|(\alpha')^{-1}(1/2)|$) for suitable automorphisms $\alpha',\beta'$. So in any case, if $\phi$ exists, we have $z_1\in\beta^{-1}(S_1)\cup(\beta')^{-1}(S_2)=:K$, which is a compact set. Thus $K\subsetneq D$. Conclude.

Comment: Thanks for the post! Why does the fact that $K$ is compact mean that $K \subsetneq D$?

Comment: Obviously $K\subseteq D$ and $K$ can't equal the whole $D$ because $D$ is not compact.

Comment: This is just a rigorous way of proving the intuitive fact that two smooth curves (1-dimensional objects) can't cover all of $D$ (which is 2-dimensional).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The part of your argument I don't buy is that $K$ depends on $\beta$ and $\alpha$, so you can only pick $z_1$ to lie outside of $K$ after you've already picked a given $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I think you need to use the fact that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are essentially unique at some point.

Comment: You can fix $\alpha$ and $\beta$ at the beginning, immediately after choosing $z_0$. They do not depend on the particular $\phi$.

Comment: But if you pick that after choosing $z_0$ you can't ensure that $z_0$ will lie outside of $K$, since $K$ depends on $\alpha$ and $\beta$, right?

Comment: Who cares about $z_0$ belonging or not to $K$? :) If you re-read the argument, it should prove that, once you fix $z_0$, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$, *if* a biholomorphism $\phi$ exists *then* $z_1\in K$. Thus if we ensure that $z_1\not\in K$ we are done.

Comment: I meant $z_1$. We can't ensure in advance that $z_1$ will lie outside of $K$, since $K$ depends on the other functions.

Comment: $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ depend just on $z_0$, thus $K$ too depends just on $z_0$ and we can choose any $z_1\not\in K$.

Comment: Yes but there different $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that satisfy the given conditions, so it could be that you pick $z_1$ to lie outside $K$ but for different functions $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ it will lie inside $K'$, where $K'$ is the $K$ corresponding to $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$.

Comment: Of course there are many $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s available. Just choose them once for all and read again the answer and the comments above

Comment: I don't think this is as trivial as you're making it out. The fact that there are many $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s means that you have to ensure that $z_1$ is not in ANY of the $K$'s corresponding to all the $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s, which means that it can't be in the union of all such $K$, and the union doesn't have to be compact. So the compactness part of your argument breaks down.

Comment: What I have shown: fix any $\alpha$ and $\beta$, choose explicit ones if you prefer. If $\phi$ exists then $z_1\in K$ for this $K$. So, in your terms, letting  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ vary, $z_1$ would have to belong to all the possible $K$'s. The logical transposition is: if this fails even for just one $K$ then $\phi$ cannot exist.

Comment: Why? Please read carefully my explanations. I do not want to discuss these basic pieces of logic and I'm beginning to think you are a troll.

Comment: The problem is that for each different $K$ you pick a different $z_1$ so that it's not inside it. What you need is to pick a $z_1$ in advance so it doesn't lie in any of the $K$'s, that is, so it doesn't lie in the union of the $K$'s, but at this point you need the compactness part of your argument, which we can't use since the union of the $K$'s isn't necessarily compact.

Comment: I'm thinking seriously about this problem, I ask you to also think seriously about my objection.

Comment: Also, your disparaging language ('basic pieces of logic', using terms like 'obviously') doesn't help anyone, and makes you come across as a jerk.

Comment: The fact is that one $K$ suffices. My final attempt to convince you: choose $z_0=1/2$ and write down an explicit $\alpha$ and an explicit $\beta$. Now stick to these and forget that they could vary. Follow the proof imagining them in your mind with the explicit expressions. Maybe it is the "genericity" of them which confuses you, so using explicit ones is better.